# Why can only females pilot IS?

Tags: infinite-stratos

Why is it that females can pilot IS and males cannot? Is there a special reason? Also, why is it that Ichika can pilot IS?

Comment: Because it is aimed for male audience.

Answer (score 2):

**Why only female can pilot IS ?**

> The reason why only females can activate the IS (and why [Ichika
> Orimura](http://is.wikia.com/wiki/Ichika_Orimura) is the only male who can do the same) is currently unknown.
> But it is hinted in the novel that [Tabane Shinonono](http://is.wikia.com/wiki/Tabane_Shinonono), the creator of
> IS, did not deliberately configure IS to be a female-only platform.
> She mentions that **it was a accidental side-effect, and since she
> didn't really care about that factor, she didn't see any reason to
> bother with it**.

[Source](http://is.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Stratos_%28IS%29)

**Why Ichika is the only male IS pilot ?**

> A speculation on why Ichika can pilot IS.
>
> By ShadowFiend1000
>
> This is my theory behind it, I think the reason why Ichika can pilot
> IS is due to Tabane pulling strings at the back. One possbility is
> that Ichika is not related to Chifuyu, and like Adam Jensen from Deus
> Ex Human Revolution along with JC Denton of Deus Ex, is genetically
> altered. This truth is possibly known to Chifuyu, Madoka and maybe
> Tabane only.
>
> For those who never played the game. In Human Revolution, mechanical
> augmentations require the user to use a drug for life to prevent
> gilial tissue build up in order to use the augmentation. Adam was
> genetically altered (unknown to himself) by White Helix resulting his
> body would not form any gilial tissue. This is a secret only David
> Serif and his girlfriend Megan knows about. And it plays a big plot in
> the game as well.
>
> Do you guys see the link here now? You might ask who altered Ichika?
> My guess, is Phantom Task.
>
> If this is true, it might serve as a massive plot point considering
> how many leaders of the world would want to bio mod their soldiers to
> wear IS.

[Source](http://is.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:4489)